# How to get all data in Audited table with hibernate envers?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have a project where i have all my entities. And I have another project where I try to get all the data of each Audited table of each given Entity.
With Hibernate envers i know how to retrieve an object in a previous version.

```
AuditReaderFactory.get(Session sess) and Object AuditReader.find(Class<T> cls, Object primaryKey, Number revision)
```

But I don't know how to get All records data in an audited X with the rev et typerev field too.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you take a look at audit queries? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-queries

Comment: Thx a lot but if i understand now , to get All datas of Audited table i can do this :

this.getAuditReader().createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(MyEnitity.class, false, true).getResultList();

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand your question that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because i want to get a lot of data from an audited table (in some table i find the millions of revisions so to get that they take a lot of time whitch cause a timout for the server , specialy when i use hibernate envers , that why i change to native query and i found a lot of possibilities and fonctionalities in.